# How can you get doctl completion working in fish shell?

Tags: autocomplete, digital-ocean, fish

**doctl** is the digitalocean cli tool for interfacing with digitalocean resources via CLI.

It has completion options built-in, for example you can run this command to enable bash completion

```
doctl completion bash > /etc/bash_completion.d/doctl
```

(may need to sudo tee the right side)

But I have been unable to figure out how to get autocompletion for fish shell working.

The doctl cli does not provide the syntax or example command.

I tried this, but it doesn't work

```
doctl completion fish > .config/fish/completions/doctl
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I tried this, but it doesn't work
> doctl completion fish > .config/fish/completions/doctl

You're *almost* right. The completion file needs to have a ".fish" extension:

```
doctl completion fish > ~/.config/fish/completions/doctl.fish
```

(also I added `~/` to make it an absolute path)